# Large Objects Within Stackrel

Tags: math-mode, fontsize

Is there a possible way to create large objects inside of `stackrel`? 
This is how I tried to do it, but it gave many errors.

```
\( \stackrel{\large Paragraph}{1} \)
```

With a `LARGE` 1 as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just because you want to, here's a way how. Put whichever portion of `\stackrel` in an `\mbox`. This forces it to text mode, where you can use `\large` (or other font sizes):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\(\stackrel{\mbox{\small text}}{1}\ %
  \stackrel{\mbox{text}}{1}\ %
  \stackrel{\mbox{\large text}}{1}\ %
  \stackrel{\mbox{\Large text}}{1}\ %
  \stackrel{\mbox{\LARGE text}}{1}\ %
  \stackrel{\mbox{\Huge text}}{1}\)
\end{document}
```

This also holds for the lower portion.

Comment: Thanks Werner: Is there a better way to do this? I was unsure. You said it as if this is not the way to go about doing it.

Comment: There are other options, like [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `\overset` command as well, which has a little better math formatting/spacing. However, I'm not exactly sure what the context is of your request, and therefore do not know what the end result should look like/fit in with. Perhaps you could elaborate?

Comment: Okay I see. Yes, I forgot about the `overset` command. It was pretty much to classify chunks of information as groups and each group inside of brackets and have them labeled. Which is the part I had asked a question about. I can update question if needed.

Comment: I guess this approach would work. You could also use `\overbrace` to identify "chunks" (if that refers to `1` in your example). If you're after an opinion of other ways of doing this, I would suggest asking a new question and referencing this one. To that end, include what you've done, perhaps even a graphic of what it is you're after if you can't recreate it in LaTeX.